# how to get all child node list values from Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image: My Database]

So this is how my database looks like. Each user can add his 3 best players that are stored in userId/My Players/ path as a Map<"Best Players", Player> as it is shown here:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(first.getText().toString());
    list.add(second.getText().toString());
    list.add(third.getText().toString());
    Players players = new Players(list);

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Best Players", players);

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    if (user != null) {
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("My Players");
        myRef.setValue(map);
    }
```

Player object contains ArrayList with 3 String objects. So, I would like to go through all users in database and search for each users 0th or 1st or 2nd player from his Best Players list. Any advice how to do that?

Comment: And what do you want to make with those lists? Do you want to display them in a `ListView`?

Comment: yes, the idea is that 0th element will be user's best player, so for example I want to display all the 0th elements, so I can see who is the best player from all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display those lists, please use this code:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId).child("My Players").child("Best Players").child("list");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    String firstList = (String) map.get("0");
    String secondList = (String) map.get("1");
    String thirdList = (String) map.get("2");
    arrayList.add(firstList + ", " + secondList + ", " + thirdList);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Not working, I get this error:  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Collections is not supported, please use Lists instead

Comment: Please change to mode in which you add data to your Firebase database. `map.put("Best Players", players);` is wrong, because `players` is an `ArrayList` and not a `Map`. Change the `list` with a `map`. Will solve your problem.

Comment: It helped! But I still get data only from logged user.. Since I have to put userId in database path.. Is there a way to go around it and get the data from all users?

Comment: Glad i could help. In this case, you can feel free to accept my answer. Regarding your last question, when you use the push() method, to generate those unique kesy, is the moment in which you can get those keys like this: String userId = ref.getKey() and after that, you can do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use code given below: change parameters as per your database

```
databaseReference.child(Table_Dashboard).orderByChild("title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            spin = new ArrayList<String>();
           // spin.add("Dashboard");


            for (DataSnapshot spinnerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String areaName = spinnerSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                spin.add(areaName);


            }

           // spin.remove("Family Details");

            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Dashboard.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    spin);
            spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
            dismissprogress();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            dismissprogress();
        }
    });
```