# How Can I Use FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is  my Firebase Database structure, I want get the value of Image, Song and Singer name, but the problem is that both values has different parent, so my question is that how can I get these values when using FirebaseListAdapter.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myina.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAbUi.png)

My Code Is Below

```
  databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Album List");



    FirebaseListAdapter adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(this , String.class
            , R.layout.list ,
            databaseReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Object model, int position) {

            ImageView Image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Images);
            TextView Song = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            TextView Singer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.SongURL);


        }
    };
```

Comment: Please take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231681/how-to-get-all-child-node-list-values-from-firebase-database/43232077#43232077). It will help you.

Comment: Thanks Sir , But I Have Already Done With Help Of DatatSnapshot , but i want do that with using firebaseListAdapter , so I think I will Change my database Structure .

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseUI` unwraps the snapshot for you and binds it to a listView. If you want  to handle the data in the snapshot differently, you will have to sub class an `ArrayAdapter` and create an XML file that will carry the views of each item on the list. you can find an example [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)